# Find the limit of $(\pi/2 - \arctan(x))^{1/\ln(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I can't find a way to continue with this calculation of limit:

$$\underset{x\to \infty }{\lim} \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(x)\right)^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}
=\underset{x\to \infty }{\lim} e^{\frac{\ln(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(x))}{\ln(x)}}.$$
Because the limit in the exponent is of the form $0/0$.
I used L'Hôpital's rule on this:
$$\underset{x\to \infty }{\lim} {\frac{\ln(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(x))}{\ln(x)}}=\underset{x\to \infty }{\lim} \frac{\frac{-1}{(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(x)) \cdot (1+x^2)}}{\frac{1}{x}}.$$

But from here I'm getting expressions without limits.

Comment: Hint: $\pi/2-\arctan(x)=\arctan(1/x)$ and $\arctan( w)=w-w^3/3 + \ldots$ as $w\to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $y:=1/x$ this becomes$$\exp\left(-\lim_{y\to0^+}\frac{\ln \arctan y}{\ln y}\right)=\exp\left(-\lim_{y\to0^+}\frac{\frac{1}{\arctan y}\frac{1}{1+y^2}}{\frac1y}\right)=\exp\left(-\lim_{y\to0^+}\frac{y}{\arctan y}\right)=\frac1e,$$because $\lim_{y\to0^+}\frac{1}{1+y^2}=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why ln(x) became ln(y) but not (1/y)?

Comment: @leeLight $\ln x=\ln\frac1y=-\ln y$; that's where the exponent got its $-$ sign.